# Max and group by query help

Tags: mysql

We have query as below. What we need is to select particular training with latest date and only single data but now when we run the query below we get more then one results.

```
SELECT tblTraining.clientTrainingID AS lastID, MAX( tblTraining.trainingDate ) AS lastDate
FROM tblTraining
WHERE tblTraining.trainedID =37
GROUP BY tblTraining.clientTrainingID
```

Comment: I have solved it.

Comment: Can you share the solution?  Was it a problem in your data?

Comment: No it was the problem with the group by I added wrong key there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT 
  tblTraining.clientTrainingID AS lastID,
  MAX( tblTraining.trainingDate ) AS lastDate
 FROM tblTraining
 WHERE tblTraining.trainedID =37
 GROUP BY tblTraining.clientTrainingID
 ORDER BY tblTraining.clientTrainingID desc
 LIMIT 1
```

This will order the max() and limit the result to the first line being the highest value.

Comment: What about having 1M rows in that table? How to optimize that?